# borg backup is processing all files instead of modified

Tags: backup, diff, snapshot, borg-backup, ceph

please advise how to correctly make borgbackup to process and copy only modified source files and their diffs to destination?

every week we make our data snapshot in cephfs:

```
/data/.snap/snap1/
/data/.snap/snap2/
```

and then borg backup of the snapshot to external machine is started.

we expect that borg will only make 1st initial long run when running borg create, and all other backups will be incremental, but backup time is not changing, and we see in logs that it processes all files, what we are doing wrong?

we use:

```
cd /data/.snap/snap1
borg create --progress --stats --list --files-cache mtime,size --compression lzma,3 ${user}@${host}:${BORGHOME}${namespace}::${backup_name} ./*
```

could problem be with different absolute path to source folder (/data/.snap/snap1, /data/.snap/snap2, and so on)? unfortunately we can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in different absolute paths of snapshot folders, creating separate folder for borg and symlinks solved the problem